# How to get the covering relation symbol?

Tags: symbols

I want    [image: cover] to denote the covering relation. I can't find this symbol in my standard sources for this sort of thing. Detextify has also failed in this. How can I get this relational symbol?

Comment: Isn't it a `\prec` symbol?

Comment: @Malipivo No. The one I ask about has only straight lines.

Comment: Very well, in case we wouldn't find that symbol, we could draw our own symbol, e.g. in TikZ.

Comment: Is a symbol like in [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X3i5q.png) good enough?

Comment: @egreg No, but the second option in your answer is looking good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use `unicode-math`, here you find a couple of possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}

\newcommand{\coveringA}{%
  \mathrel{-\mkern-4mu}<%
}
\newcommand{\coveringB}{\mathrel{\text{$\vcenter{\hbox{\pictcoveringB}}$}}}

\newcommand{\pictcoveringB}{%
  \begin{picture}(1em,.5em)
  \roundcap
  \put(0,.25em){\line(1,0){.6em}}
  \put(.6em,.25em){\line(3,1){.4em}}
  \put(.6em,.25em){\line(3,-1){.4em}}
  \end{picture}%
}

\begin{document}

$x\coveringA y_{\coveringA}$

$x\coveringB y_{\coveringB}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're sure that you won't use the symbol in subscripts or superscripts, then

```
\newcommand{\coveringB}{\mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{\pictcoveringB}}}}
```

is more efficient. You can play with the parameters as you wish, in the second solution.

Comment: I'm sure that I won't use it in subscripts or superscripts. So how exactly do I incorporate `\newcommand{\coveringB}{\mathrel{\vcenter{\hbox{\pictcoveringB}}}}` into your proposed solution?

Comment: @GitGud Just use the second proposed definition in place of the original one. Of course you don't need to define `\coveringA` and maybe give `\coveringB` a better name.

Answer (score 4):

The symbol you are looking for is [U+2919](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2919/index.htm). You could use `unicode-math` in order to get it. It is already defined as `\mathrel` here.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
$\righttail\lefttail$
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
$\righttail\lefttail$
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
$\righttail\lefttail$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you choose any font you like and do:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\lefttail}[1]{\mathrel{\fontspec{#1}\text{\symbol{"2919}}}}

\begin{document}
$x\lefttail{code2000.ttf} y$
$x\lefttail{quivira.otf} y$
$x\lefttail{stix-regular.otf} y$
$x\lefttail{symbola.ttf} y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some of them will need some vertical adjustment, though.

---

You may also want to take a look on [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4mm]
x & y\arrow[no head, tail]{l}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]